# Finding the count of matching cart items in an array with the same values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm sorry if this exact question has been answered, but scanning through SO I've yet to find the answer and I'm just not able to wrap my head around how to solve this.

If I have an array of items in a cart for example:

```
$cartItems = array ( 
    "0" => array ( 'category' => 'car', 'model' => 'high', 'number'=> 14 ),
    "1" => array ( 'category' => 'car', 'model' => 'low', 'number'=> 16 ), 
    "2" => array ( 'category' => 'bike', 'model' => 'high', 'number'=> 14 ), 
    "3" => array ( 'category' => 'bike', 'model' => 'high', 'number'=> 14 ), 
    "4" => array ( 'category' => 'bike', 'model' => 'low', 'number'=> 16 ), 
    "5" => array ( 'category' => 'car', 'model' => 'high', 'number'=> 18 ), 
    "6" => array ( 'category' => 'bike', 'model' => 'high', 'number'=> 18 ), 
    "7" => array ( 'category' => 'bike', 'model' => 'high', 'number'=> 19 ) );
```

I want to be able to find the count of cars and bikes that have the same model and number.

So 1 car/high/14 and 2 bike/high/14s. Or 1 car/high/18 and 1 bike/high/18. The end goal being that I can then apply quantity discounts for matching items.

EDIT: The complication here is that there are 2 categories, 2 models, and 10 number types. Which creates a lot of variations to go through.

The more I've thought about how to solve for it the more loops end up in the code! Ideally in PHP.

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a filtering function that can return the count like:

```
function filter($input, $category, $model, $number) {
    $filtered = array_filter($input, function($item) use ($category, $model, $number) {
        return $item['category'] == $category && 
        $item['model'] == $model && 
        $item['number'] == $number;
    });

    return count($filtered);
}

echo filter($cartItems, 'car', 'high', '14'); // Returns 1
echo filter($cartItems, 'bike', 'high', '14'); // Returns 2
```

Comment: Very interesting idea Cosmin. And it could work and definitely solves the problem as I wrote it. But I realize I missed a key point. There are 2 categories, 2 models, and 10 number types. Which creates a lot of variations to filter on. Totally my bad for not adding that to the OP. I'll do it now.